# All CiviCase Functionality Gone Despite Component Being Enabled

Tags: civicase

All the CiviCase functionality has gone in our CiviCRM D7 (version 5.34.0) website even though the component is enabled. All the menu items for CiviCase are not there. I have flushed all caches, reset paths and reset menus. I have disabled and re-enabled the component but this all makes no difference. If I go to `/civicrm/civicase` it redirects to `/civicrm/admin`. There don't seem to be any relevant error messages in the CiviCRM log or in the Drupal log. The CiviCase permissions are still present in Drupal.

Can anyone suggest any further troubleshooting I can do?

All other components and everything else is working fine. As far as I know there have been no significant updates to Civi either (no new extensions enabled etc)

Comment: it sounds like a permission issue but you say you have checked that the role you are using has those permissions. odd.

Comment: Agree it sounds like something with  permissions. Are you set up in a way you can run xdebug/step-debug to see what's happening when you visit civicrm/case? Or put in debug statements in the code starting at CRM/Core/Invoke.php and thru until CRM/Case/Page/Dashboard.php but might take a while to find the right spot where something interesting happens.

Comment: Thanks so much @petednz-fuzion and Demerit. It was a permissions issue. I had only checked that the permissions were there, not that they were set correctly. I forgot the first basic Drupal troubleshooting rules - clear caches then check permissions! Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it sounds like a permission issue - please check they are set for the roles being used.